# MySQL | Error - A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, partition

I'm having a problem with partition on a table in MySQL. I want to partition table `reminders` depend on quarter of year, because I think I can delete list of reminders was expired later.

Maybe, I should add field in `primary key` or `unique key` to partition work. Please help me this problem.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `reminders`
(
  `id`              bigint(20)          NOT NULL,
  `mer_reminder_id` varchar(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  `created_at`      timestamp           NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at`      timestamp           NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at`      timestamp           NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  `type`            varchar(32)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority`        int(11)                      DEFAULT NULL,
  `due`             timestamp           NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  `title`           varchar(255)                 DEFAULT NULL,
  `description`     varchar(255)                 DEFAULT NULL,
  `template`        varchar(32)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_id`       bigint(20)          NOT NULL,
  `merchant_id`     bigint(20)          NOT NULL,
  `expired`         bool                NULL     DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `created_at`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) ) (
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q1_2019 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-04-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q2_2019 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-07-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q3_2019 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q4_2019 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q1_2020 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-04-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q2_2020 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-07-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q3_2020 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-10-01 00:00:00') ),
    PARTITION zpm_reminder_reminders_q4_2020 VALUES LESS THAN ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01 00:00:00') )
    );
```

Problem: `#1503 - A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: if your table is partitioned and has a unique key, every column used in the unique key must also be used as part of the partition. You are using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at)` for partitioning, but you have a unique key on `mer_reminder_id`, so this configuration isn't valid.

My advice: don't use MySQL partitions for this. They are extremely limiting, and are often buggy as well. If you need to discard old rows in this table, use `DELETE` with a condition -- unless your table is *extremely* large, you'll spend much more time maintaining the partitions than you will save on faster delete operations.

(Unrelatedly, I see a potential design issue in your table -- the primary key in your table should probably be `id`, not `(id, created_at)`. Timestamps almost never belong in primary keys.)